# Loop for creating button in multiple row and column

Tags: c++, qt, qvboxlayout

From this code, I want to create a table of buttons followed by input (row, column).

But my GUI doesn't show the buttons in 2x4, it shows them in 1x8.

```cpp
QHBoxLayout* hl = new QHBoxLayout;
QVBoxLayout* vl = new QVBoxLayout;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
    btn_list.append(new QPushButton(this));
    hl->addWidget(btn_list[(i*2)+j]);
  }
  vl->addLayout(hl);
}
this->setLayout(vl);
```

Rendered output:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `vl->addLayout(hl);` You only have 1 horizontal layout. You need a new horizontal layout for each row. With that said you could just use a grid instead.

Comment: @drescherjm As you say, I try to understand the code again. And try to fix it. (adding QHBoxLayout from 1 to 2 layout)It appears that it works very well. Thank you very much.